# rails dynamic data hover over

Tags: ruby-on-rails, html

I am trying to create a hover over action for items inside of a dynamically created loop. I have no idea what the object names are or how many there are. As of now, I have the list printed correctly and a hover over working, however the hover over only prints the info from the first item, no matter which one you are hovering over

```
<% @reward_definitions_with_user_points.each do |definition| %>
        <li>
          <a href="#" data-class="popover-inside" data-toggle="popover-follow" data-placement="right" data-btn-edit="hover" data-target="#point-tracker-popover">
          <%= definition.first.name %><span class="points"><%= format_points(definition.second) %> pts.</span>
          </a>
          <div id="point-tracker-popover" style="display:none">
            <div class="popover-title"><%=definition.first.name%></div>
            <div class="popover-content">
              <div class="popover-inner popover-lg">
                <%=definition.first.description%><span class="points"><%= format_points(definition.first.points) %> pts.</span>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </li>
    <% end %>
```

For example: if the my list is  a,b,c,d,e,f and I want the hover over to display each letter in sequence when activated. However it will display 'a' in the hoverover no matter which one the mouse activates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should probably mention that the problem you're having is with popovers.  Also showing the html generated by your loop would be helpful. You seem to imply from the tags that popovers are an html5 thing, but I thought they were a part of twitter-bootstrap?

Having said all that...

What you are describing is clearly related to `data-target="#point-tracker-popover"`.  Which I believe is pointing to `id="point-tracker-popover"`.  The div with this id is being generated inside of your loop (having multiple elements with the same id is bad and is why you are experiencing the behavior you mentioned).

Changing your loop to use each_with_index should fix your problem.

```
<% @reward_definitions_with_user_points.each_with_index do |definition, index| %>
        <li>
          <a href="#" data-class="popover-inside" data-toggle="popover-follow" data-placement="right" data-btn-edit="hover" data-target="#point-tracker-popover-<%= index %>">
          <%= definition.first.name %><span class="points"><%= format_points(definition.second) %> pts.</span>
          </a>
          <div id="point-tracker-popover-<%= index %>" style="display:none">
            <div class="popover-title"><%=definition.first.name%></div>
            <div class="popover-content">
              <div class="popover-inner popover-lg">
                <%=definition.first.description%><span class="points"><%= format_points(definition.first.points) %> pts.</span>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </li>
    <% end %>
```

Of course, you may be able to simply change the target to a class like `data-target=".point-tracker-popover"` and change the `id="point-tracker-popover"` to be `class="point-tracker-popover"`; which would be a much cleaner approach.  I am really not familiar with popovers, though, so I cannot say if this is the only problem you have, or if the second approach will work.